# PHP MYSQL image update is not working saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

This is driving me crazy! I have stayed for 2 nights trying to solve this error. I also searched this problem all over "Google" can't seem to find the right answer.

I want to update image using PHP. The code seems to be working with the sole exception of  the error message that says:

> "43ERROR: Could not able to execute 1. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1".

Please help me! I will be very thankful.:)

```
<?php include('../db_connect.php'); 
echo $id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT * 
  FROM `blog_posts` 
 WHERE post_id='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    //-------------------WHEN SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICKED------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $post_title = $_POST['posttitle'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $author_name = $_POST['authorname'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && ($_FILES['image']['name'] !="")){
            $size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
            $temp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
            $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
            unlink("../images/"."$image_name");

            move_uploaded_file($temp,"../images/$image_name");
        }

    //-------------------UPDATE POST------------------------

        $edit = mysqli_query($con, "
UPDATE blog_posts 
   SET post_title='$post_title'
     , content='$content'
     , author_name='$author_name'
     , category='$category'
     , post_date=now()
     , image='$image_name' 
 WHERE post_id='$id'
");
        if(mysqli_query($con, $edit)){
            echo "date updated successfully";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $edit. " . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }

?>

<form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
                <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000" />
                <input type="text" name="posttitle" value="<?php echo $row['post_title'];?>" /><br />
                <textarea name="content"><?php echo $row['content'];?></textarea><br />
                <input type="text" name="authorname" value="<?php echo $row['author_name'];?>"/><br />
                <input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category'];?>"><br />
                <img src="../images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" />
                <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" >Post</button>                  
            </form>
```

Comment: I'll bet that your author name has an apostrophe in it, eg: `Joe O'Malley`, and your code is breaking for the same reason that everyone is about to crawl up your butt about SQL injection. Switch to prepared statements and not only will your code not break, it will be far less insecure as well.

Comment: Echo query .....

Comment: Separate your SQL query from and echo it, this way you can see what is breaking. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string)` to clean up your form input.

Comment: When i echo d query "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\purev\db_connect.php on line 3" showed up.

Comment: $edit should be something like this `$edit = "UPDATE blog_posts SET post_title='$post_title', content='$content', author_name='$author_name', category='$category', post_date=now(), image='$image_name' WHERE post_id='$id'";`

Comment: @Sammitch That isn't it well....that could be problemsome, yes; however the fact is that they've called `mysqli_query()` twice for the same query. However, you are right about the latter. I personally like to keep my work ;-)

Comment: @ibonly About your UPDATE syntax suggestion to the OP; that's what they are using actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (fairly) a simple one and it may sound rather odd to you, but that in a sense meant that your query did in fact execute.

Now, the reason you're getting that `1` as per the `right syntax to use near '1'` (error) message, is that you used `mysqli_query()` twice, right in here:

```
        $edit = mysqli_query($con, "
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here
UPDATE blog_posts 
   SET post_title='$post_title'
     , content='$content'
     , author_name='$author_name'
     , category='$category'
     , post_date=now()
     , image='$image_name' 
 WHERE post_id='$id'
");
        if(mysqli_query($con, $edit)){
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ and here
            echo "date updated successfully";
        }
```

What you need to do is to change that `if` statement to:

```
if($edit){
// handle your method here.
}
```

Btw, you're open to a serious sql injection; use a prepared statement if you value your work and userbase.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Yes I changed the second mysqli_query to prepared statement. But now i am getting 
"Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in".

Comment: @user2652699 that warning you say you're getting now, doesn't  support what you posted for code. I answered the originally posted question/code.

Comment: @user2652699 you would need to first close this question if it was solved, and ask a new question.

Comment: thanks for the info. Even though i am still troubleshooting the problem, your answer was the most helpful. But, how do i close the question? Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome @user2652699 well, you just did ;-) *Cheers*