# Mysql update query with prepared statement is giving error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am getting the following error in the code below.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number  of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\purev\admin\edit.php on line 39

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $post_title = $_POST['posttitle'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $author_name = $_POST['authorname'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $post_date = $_POST['postdate'];

    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && ($_FILES['image']['name'] !="")){
        $size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
        $temp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
        $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        unlink("../images/"."$image_name");

        move_uploaded_file($temp,"../images/$image_name");
    }

//-------------------UPDATE POST------------------------

    $sql = 
        "UPDATE blog_posts 
            SET post_title='$post_title', 
            content='$content', 
            author_name='$author_name', 
            category='$category', 
            post_date='$post_date',
            image='$image_name'
            WHERE post_id='$id'";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param("sssssii", $post_title, $content, $author_name, $category, $image_name, $post_date, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Without using prepared statement the query works. Do you have any any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: The error is pretty simple: you don't have the same amount of placeholders as you have variables. And reading the code, you actually don't have **any** placeholder. Check out one of the docs page for examples: [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Quickhint as to what you should be looking for: when using prepared statements with parameterized queries, you don't concatenated / interpolate the variables, you use `?` as placeholders.

Comment: Hello @FirstOne, I went on and applied the changes but now it gives me "FAILURE!!! No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement". Could you explain what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's been said in comments, you missed the placeholders.

So, change:

```
$sql = 
    "UPDATE blog_posts 
        SET post_title='$post_title', 
        content='$content', 
        author_name='$author_name', 
        category='$category', 
        post_date='$post_date',
        image='$image_name'
        WHERE post_id='$id'";
```

to:

```
$sql = 
    "UPDATE blog_posts 
        SET post_title=?, 
        content=?, 
        author_name=?, 
        category=?, 
        post_date=?, 
        image=? 
        WHERE post_id=?";
```

It's as simple as that.

The manual contains the proper syntax:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

---

Don't forget to **pass the arguments in the correct order**. They should be passed in the same order as they are used in the query (you swapped the image with post date), so it should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssisi", $post_title, $content, $author_name, $category, $post_date, $image_name, $id);
```

Comment: Updated the order of arguments in the binding. I'm not sure the letters are in the correct order now, but I updated them too.

Comment: Thanks @FirstOne that was an oversight on my part. They seem to have had the same ordering in their previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48087290/1415724 which I informed them to use a prepared statement. They went ahead and did it, however they may have made an oversight also.

Comment: Those things are easy to miss, @FunkFortyNiner, so I went on looking for them ;)

Comment: Hello @FunkFortyNiner, I went on and applied the changes but now it gives me "FAILURE!!! No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement". What was the reason.