# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\Latihan\login.php on line 33

```
<?php  require_once 'connect.php';

$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
33.            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            //$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the username to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        //mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you have mistaken this website for pastebin?

Comment: Read the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123286/mysql-update-query-with-prepared-statement-is-giving-error), as the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, you need to have `?` placeholders in the query that will be replaced with the parameters. This is done *instead* of concatenating the variable directly into the query string.

The error means that the number of parameters in your `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` call doesn't match the number of `?` in the SQL.

So take the variable out of `$sql` and put `?` there.

```
$sql = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Comment: What are the odds of two [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123286/mysql-update-query-with-prepared-statement-is-giving-error)s with the same specific problem to pop in such short period of time?

Comment: @FirstOne Upvote my answer so I can link it as a dupe.

Comment: If you want to post an answer there, I'll upvote it and make this the dupe.

Comment: @FirstOne the difference with Barmar's and the answer I gave for the other question you linked, is that I made mine a community wiki. I feel that questions like that should be given wiki answers. They're typos, so there shouldn't be any rep gain/loss, but an answer nonetheless would be good to have, sure.

Comment: wait a minute; you placed an answer yet you dupe it after, what gives? any special reason? maybe you're thinking canonical?

Comment: Actually, typos have an specific flag, but it's fine. Don't think too much about it @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @FirstOne The other answer didn't exist when I posted mine. Just trying to link related questions together.

Comment: I don't consider this a typo, it's a conceptual problem.

Comment: Although in these cases it's probably just a case of starting to convert from variables to prepared statements, and not completing the process.